# Can anyone help me with IF statement in formula?

Tags: formula, syntax-highlighting

I am trying to add another logical test to my formula. At the moment my formula checks the record type of an opportunity and generates a unique ID number in the formula field.

The formula works fine, and now I want the formula field to be populated when the opportunity stage equals "Invoice".

So basically,I want to add "ISPICKVAL( StageName , "Invoice")" to the below formula.

IF(OPCC__c = ""  , IF(OPPS__c = "",  IF(OPET__c = "", IF(LMS__c = "", "",  LMS__r.CustAuto__c ),  OPET__r.CustAuto__c ) , OPPS__r.CustAuto__c) ,  OPCC__r.CustAuto__c )

I am having trouble adding this criteria to the below formula as I am unsure of the syntax when using "IF" & "AND" Statements in formula's

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow, That's some mess.
Could you give a record as example..

Also if you only wish to add ISPICKVAL( StageName , "Invoice") and If I under stand it correctly, then can you try this

```
IF(
ISPICKVAL( StageName , "Invoice"),
IF(OPCC__c = "" , 
IF(OPPS__c = "", 
IF(OPET__c = "", 
IF(LMS__c = "", 
"", 
LMS__r.CustAuto__c ), 
OPET__r.CustAuto__c ) , 
OPPS__r.CustAuto__c) , 
OPCC__r.CustAuto__c ),
"")
```

Comment: Perfect. That's what I needed A-D

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you want correctly, this should do the trick:

```
IF (
    ISPICKVAL(StageName , "Invoice"),
    IF (
        OPCC__c = "" , 
        IF (
            OPPS__c = "", 
            IF (
                OPET__c = "", 
                IF (
                    LMS__c = "", 
                    "", 
                    LMS__r.CustAuto__c 
                ), 
                OPET__r.CustAuto__c 
            ), 
            OPPS__r.CustAuto__c
        ),
        OPCC__r.CustAuto__c
    ),
    ""
)
```

I always find it easier to structure formulas in a code like manner, as complex formulas can get confusing.

Comment: Hi Davin, Thanks for the help. I think I am almost there. My formula now looks like this  "IF(ISPICKVAL(StageName , "Invoice"),IF(OPCC__c = ""  ,  IF(OPPS__c = "",  IF(OPET__c = "", IF(LMS__c = "", "",  LMS__r.CustAuto__c ),  OPET__r.CustAuto__c ) , OPPS__r.CustAuto__c) ,  OPCC__r.CustAuto__c ))"   But it is giving me the error "Error: Incorrect number of parameters for function 'IF()'. Expected 3, received 2"    Any Ideas?